# save 2 kinds of data using one filestream?

Tags: actionscript-3, save, filestream

Im saving 2 kinds of data(text and image). Is it possible to save 2 types of data at the same time using 1 filestream? example

```
var myTextFileObj:Object = new Object()
myTextFileObj["Name"]="George Borming" 
var imgByteData:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(myBitmapData);//lets assume i have a bitmap data here

var folder:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("myApp/images/image.jpg");
var folder2:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("myApp/textfiles/mytext.txt");

fileStream = new FileStream();  
fileStream.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, saveImg_FS_fileClosed);
fileStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, saveImg_FS_completeHandler); 
fileStream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, saveImg_FS_progressHandler); 
fileStream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, saveImg_FS_errorHandler); 

fileStream.openAsync(folder, FileMode.UPDATE);  
fileStream.writeBytes(imgByteData)

fileStream.openAsync(folder2, FileMode.UPDATE);  
fileStream.writeObject(myTextFileObj);
fileStream.close();
```

Will this work?Is it possible or would it be better if i would just create 2 filestream and save the datas seperately. IF it is possible and my code is wrong, please can you teach me the right codes.

Comment: not possible, use 2 FileStream.

Comment: @BotMaster - Of course it's possible...  Why waste memory and make redundant code (adding all those listeners) when you don't have to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly possible.  The likely issue though, is that you are using `openAsync`, so the file stream operation is still in progress when you try open another file and you don't close the first file before opening the second.

You either you need to **wait until the first operation completes** before starting the second, or **open the files synchronously** using `open` instead of `openAsync`.

**FOR EXAMPLE:**

```
var folder:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("myApp/images/image.jpg");

fileStream = new FileStream();  
fileStream.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, saveImg_FS_fileClosed);
fileStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, saveImg_FS_completeHandler); 
fileStream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, saveImg_FS_progressHandler); 
fileStream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, saveImg_FS_errorHandler); 

fileStream.open(folder, FileMode.UPDATE);  //use open instead of open Async
fileStream.writeBytes(imgByteData)
fileStream.close(); //close the current File so you can open a new one

folder = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("myApp/textfiles/mytext.txt");
fileStream.open(folder, FileMode.UPDATE);  
fileStream.writeObject(myTextFileObj);
fileStream.close();
```

---

If your two files are always opened / saved together, you may find it cleaner to use a custom class/model for the items you want to save, then use `FileStream.writeObject` to serialize that class to just one file.

**Something like this:**

```
package {
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class SaveData {
        public var textFile:Object;
        public var imageByteData:ByteArray;
        //any other properties
    }
}
```

Then, you can do this: (in your constructor or wherever)

```
flash.net.registerClassAlias("SaveData",SaveData);
flash.net.registerClassAlias("flash.utils.ByteArray",ByteArray);
//you have to register every non primitive class referenced by SaveData (including nested classes)
```

Then to save it to file, you do something along these lines:

```
var myTextFileObj:Object = new Object()
myTextFileObj["Name"]="George Borming";

var mySaveData:SaveData = new SaveData();
mySaveData.textFile = myTextFileObj;
mySaveData.imageByteData = jpgEncoder.encode(myBitmapData);//lets assume i have a bitmap data here

var folder:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("myApp/mySaveData.data");

fileStream = new FileStream();  
fileStream.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, saveImg_FS_fileClosed);
fileStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, saveImg_FS_completeHandler); 
fileStream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, saveImg_FS_progressHandler); 
fileStream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, saveImg_FS_errorHandler); 

fileStream.openAsync(folder, FileMode.WRITE);  

//serialize it to the file with writeObject
fileStream.writeObject(mySaveData);
fileStream.close();
```

---

```
//then later when you want to read it back in
var mySaveData:SaveData = fileStream.readObject();
trace(mySaveData.textFile["Name"]); //George Borming
```

This way you can have as many objects as you want in 1 file.

Comment: So i should put the saving of the image(JPG) in the SaveData Class?

    var folder:File=File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("myApp/images/image.jpg");

Comment: You're putting your image data and any other data you want to save in an instance of the `SaveData` class, then you're saving that instance.

Comment: Did you get it working?  Do you actually want two separate physical files?  Or do you just want to reuse the same FileSream on two separate operations?

Comment: Yes 2 separate files. Yes if its possible i would like to use only 1 Filestream for 2 operations.. Currently i used 2 FileStream.  Run FileStream1 for the text, then after the  Filestream1 is over, the FileStream2 runs. This works but i notice that it takes time to finish. Let me explain.. I have this drop-down menu button that when you click it, New,Open,Save options appear.. When i click save, the menu button SHOULD go back to its original place INSTANTLY. But currently its not. The menu waits for the FileStream to be over before it sets itself back to its original place..

Comment: Yea, your issue is your saving asynchronously, so you need to listen and wait for the complete event before saving the next file.  OR, just save synchronously... I'll show an example in my answer (I though your goal was to have 1 file)

Comment: I want to try this custom class. I just have a few questions before i start. Forgive me if some of these questions are stupid questions..
    1.) Is it really possible to create a file that contains both texts and image?
    2.) What does this do? registerClassAlias? Explain in simple terms. Cant i just create a new actionscript file and create the SaveData class there. And just import the Actioncsript file so i can use it..

Comment: 1   Yes.   2.   Register class alias basically tells flash how to encode a class to the AMF (Action Message Format) - which is basically a serialized  format that can easily be sent outside of flash (like sending data to a server or a shared object or file)