# AS3 Savinig / Exporting a Vector

Tags: actionscript-3, vector, export

Is it possible to 'Save' a Vector?

Let me explain, I want to store some classes so I can load them at a later date. e.g.

```
var cats:Vector<Cat> = new Vector<Cat>;

// Make lots of cats
```

Can I export / Save this 'cats' Vector into a file that I can then import back into my program?

Comment: Yes.  It's possible.  Look up [storing local data](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d80.html) and the SharedObject class for one approach.

Comment: What is your platform?  Web?  Air? Projector?  Also, what is the nature of your `Cat` class?  is it a display object? simple Object?   For non-display objects, it's incredibly easy with AMF - either to a physical file or shared object (cookie) - or even a database somewhere.

Comment: You can see the second half of my answer here for a good AIR example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30667151/save-2-kinds-of-data-using-one-filestream/30669308#30669308

Answer (score 0):

AMF Reading and writing objects via byte arrays is the way to go:

> The readObject() and writeObject() methods read an object from and
>   write an object to a ByteArray, encoded in serialized Action Message
>   Format (AMF).

Ref: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7d54.html

Comment: Consider making your answer much more useful by providing an example instead of just a link.    There are a lot of nuances that make this method challenging for display objects (though it's unclear what type of Object `Cat` is).